# Japanese Yew: "Podocarpus macrophyllus" vs. "Taxus cuspidata"

Tags: identification

Both "Podocarpus macrophyllus" and "Taxus cuspidata" have "Japanese Yew" as a common name.

What distinguishing features do they have to help me determine which genus of plant I have?

[image]

Comment: A photo would help in determining that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is straight copy/paste from Wikipedia:

> Taxus cuspidata ... is an evergreen tree or large shrub growing to
> 10–18 m tall, with a trunk up to 60 cm diameter. The leaves are
> lanceolate, flat, dark green, 1–3 cm long and 2–3 mm broad, arranged
> spirally on the stem, but with the leaf bases twisted to align the
> leaves in two flattish rows either side of the stem except on erect
> leading shoots where the spiral arrangement is more obvious.
>
> The seed cones are highly modified, each cone containing a single seed
> 4–8 mm long partly surrounded by a modified scale which develops into
> a soft, bright red berry-like structure called an aril, 8–12 mm long
> and wide and open at the end.

And

> Podocarpus macrophyllus ... is a small to medium-sized evergreen tree,
> reaching 20 m (66 ft) tall.[4] The leaves are strap-shaped, 6–12 cm
> (2.4–4.7 in) long, and about 1 cm broad, with a central midrib. The
> cones are borne on a short stem, and have two to four scales, usually
> only one (sometimes two) fertile, each fertile scale bearing a single
> apical seed 10–15 mm. When mature, the scales swell up and become
> reddish purple, fleshy, and berry-like, 10–20 mm long.

The taxus leaves look a lot smaller than the podocarpus leaves. The fruiting bodies look very different as well. A picture is worth a thousand words, so take a good look at the images in the two Wikipedia articles.

Comment: Podocarpus Macrophyllus makes a nice house plant in the right situation and a yew needs outdoor temperature ranges